# .isDisplayed condition in while loop gives "Element Not Found Exception"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get all columns on this particular page and using below, there is something that I am not doing right, because it is giving element not found exception. According to me it should not go inside while loop as condition doesn't hold true, then whats the mistake here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        String xpathstart = "html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li[";
        String xpathends="]/a";

        driver.get("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/");
        int i=1;
        while(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathstart+i+xpathends)).isDisplayed()){
            System.out.println("current column value is"+i);    
            i++;

        }
        System.out.println("total colored columns are "+i);
    }
```

I didn't ask alternative of while loop (to use for loop, that i already know)

What it is working in selenium RC

```
while(selenium.isElementPresent(xpathstarts+i+xpathends))
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the findElement doesn't find the element you are referring to in your XPath. The simplest solution for you would be to use findElements instead:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    String xpath = "html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li";

    driver.get("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/");
    int i=1;
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
        System.out.println("current column value is"+i);    

    }

    System.out.println("total colored columns are "+elements.size());
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but I knew how to make this code work using for loop. I wanted to know why condition specified in selenium rc working but not in webdriver.

Comment: @paul That's because WebDriver.findElement throws NoSuchElementException when an element is not found: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By). With selenium RC you used isElementPresent. You can use the same Selenium.isElementPresent in your Java code.

Comment: How can I use , Selenium.isElementPresent with WebDriver ??

Answer (score -1):

`isDisplayed()` should be used to check the visibility of element and the precondition to use this method is element source code must be present on page source code either in hidden or visible mode.If element source doesn't exist on page source then it returns 'Element not found exception'. If you more curious to know the visibility status of element then I'll suggest to use try-catch with `isDisplayed()` to avoid the exception.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/");

String xpathToFindAllElements = "html/body/div[2]/div/ul/li/a";

List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath));

// Try-catch block ensures element is visible on page 
try {
    for(element : allElements){
       if(element.isDisplayed()){
           System.out.println("Element is visible");
           }
       }
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Its not working , its again element not found exception.

Comment: **Element not found exception** specifies that exception is at `driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath))` because `.isDisplayed()` condition has been kept in try-catch so it can never throw any exception. Have you checked this xpath. Is it correct? If yes then please try to upgrade jar version.